# Problema con lectura de Webhook en PHP

Tags: php

Hola espero se encuentren bien, estaría agradecido de su ayuda y orientación.

Una empresa de envíos llamada driv.in me indica que puedo leer una serie de datos mediante su webhook, para ello debo proporcionarles una URL de destino y yo encargarme de cómo procesar dichos datos. Les eh indicado que los datos deben ser enviados a https://franixexpress.cl/index.php, por lo que me indican que de su parte el webhook se esta enviando correctamente, ahora bien, estoy implementando el siguiente código para poder leer el webhook, pero siempre obtengo como respuesta un NULL, estaré haciéndolo mal o directamente es problema del webhook.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');


$requestData = file_get_contents('php://input');


$decodedData = json_decode($requestData, true);


if ($decodedData === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    echo 'Error al decodificar los datos JSON del webhook.';
} else {

    $formattedData = json_encode($decodedData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


    $logFile = 'request.log';
    $fp = file_put_contents($logFile, $formattedData);


    if ($fp !== false) {
        echo 'Datos registrados correctamente.';
    } else {
        echo 'Error al escribir en el archivo de registro.';
    }
}


if (file_exists($logFile)) {
    $logContent = file_get_contents($logFile);

    if ($logContent !== false) {
        echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($logContent) . '</pre>';
    } else {
        echo 'No se pudo leer el archivo de registro.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'El archivo de registro no existe.';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola Jonathan, tené en cuenta que la variable `$logFile` solo se define cuando se envían datos. Considera definirla fuera del `else`, y ahí si, si no se enviaron datos y si existe el archivo vas a poder ver los datos.

Comment: Eh definido la variable $logFile = 'request.log';, debajo de $requestData , pero aun asi el archivo request.log, solo tiene un dato que dice NULL